# cannot set freq 44100 to ep 0x1 : what does it mean?

Tags: usb, external-soundcard

With a 'dmesg', I read dozens of error messages 'cannot set freq 44100 to ep 0x1' which are caused by plugging headphones having its own USB sound card (the ASUS ROG Spitfire). These headphones actually work very well. What is going on ?

Answer (score 1):

Encountered this issue in Ubuntu 22.

Switching to pipewire helped:

```
sudo apt install pipewire-pulse wireplumber
```

then reboot and replug the sound card